# Nodejs error EPERM: File creation error on remote windows server following upgrade to node 8.10.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

We have recently upgraded from Node 0.12.2 to 8.10.0 on our test server. We are now getting -4048 EPERM when we try to export a Json file. So we went back to the previous version of Node and we are getting the same error! We can write files to that directory from windows and also have created a small node js file to write files to the remote server and it works. We have tried completely removing node and reinstalling (including several server reboots and got nowhere). We initially tried npm cache clear (`--force`) in both powershell and cmd at admin level after reading several posts and this did not work.  The test server is not open so we cannot run `npm install` for example against `package.json`. Has anyone had a similar problem?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The account the node service was running on was the wrong one and didn't have permissions for the remote server - simple as.